# Google +1 number variations

Tags: google, social-media, google-plus-one

I've been looking at this for a few days now, our Google+1 count on our homepage is +206 when I am signed into my Google account, but comes out as 198 when I am not signed in to my Google account!

What is going on here, any ideas?  The url is http://www.scirra.com if you need to look for yourself.

Thanks for any help, I don't see it as a big issue but I'm curious more than anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW I see the same count logged in as logged out...

In general, it's not worth worrying about differences like that, as there are situations where the count would be cached and shown slightly differently depending on who/when you check it. For a more complete view of the +1 button counts, I'd recommend checking out [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) where there's a whole section devoted to [+1 button metrics](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1140191).